# content editable div html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="dropZone"></div>

<div class="imageHolder">
    <div class="droppedImage"></div>
</div>
```

I have the above html. There maybe a few 'dropZone' divs on the page. But each is has the following event bound:

```
$('#lightbox').find('.dropZone').each(function(){
    $(this).mouseover(function(){
        // check the asset is an image 
        if( $(this).find('img').length > 0 ){
            var src = $(this).find('img').first().attr('src'),
                masterTestVal = 'mydomain';
            $(this).empty();

            // check the asset is from the image bin
            if(src.search(masterTestVal) > 0){
                var that = $(this).siblings('.imageHolder').find('.droppedImage'),
                    img = '<img src="'+src+'"/>';
                that.html(img);
            } else {
                alert('Only images from your image bin are accepted here.');
            }
        } else {
            if($(this).html().length > 0){
                alert('Only images from your image bin are accepted here.');
                $(this).empty();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The idea is simple, a user can drag and drop an image from their 'image bin' another div loaded on the page populated with some preloaded images. When the user drags an image over a 'drop zone' div the above js kicks in, if the image is from my domain then the said image is copied into the 'droppedImage' div.

This works perfectly well, but in chrome and safari the user can only do this action once. In firefix I can repeat the action endlessly. But in chome and safari is seems after one drop the attr contenteditable is lost or something?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
John

js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n6EgH/1/

Comment: can you create fiddle for that???

Comment: I second the request for a reduced test case (using one of the many tools: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/), [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), etc).

Comment: You really should provide at last CSS for this...

Comment: Hi, ok i have reproduced the effect in a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/n6EgH/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kooilnc
Your answer definitely feels right, using the drag drop behaviour, however as of yet i have yet to find the time to understand the drag drop events properly.

As a bodge fix, i have found a work around although it does feel messy. I have simply removed the drop-zone div in Q and replaced with a new version plus rebound the events after an img drop. So kind of just starting it all over again :S

```
 // check the asset is from the image bin
                        if(src.search(masterTestVal) > 0){
                            var that = $(this).siblings('.imageHolder').find('.droppedImage'),
                                img = '<img src="'+src+'"/>';
                            that.html(img);
                            $(that).attr('contenteditable','true')
                            var newDropBin = $('<div contenteditable="true">'); // <= replacing the original drop zone here
                            $(this).replaceWith(newDropBin);
                            $(newDropBin).addClass('drop-zone');
                            dropImg.init();
                        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6EgH/4/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $(this).mouseover, try to bind mouseover on that div. I think this would work. Use $(this).bind('mouseover',function()..

Comment: Hi, thanks but no joy. In chrome the event an only happen once. After the first drop you cannot drop any more images.

Comment: When are you binding this event? and do you recreate img div after drop?

Comment: I implemented the code as http://jsfiddle.net/n6EgH/4/  I tried your suggestion of bind but this didn't fix it. And yes the fix i wrote included rebuilding the drop div after each use. But also rebinding the event

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684075/content-editable-div-html/18684401?noredirect=1#answer-18694211